# What actually is interval of two notes?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

In my book, it is written that if the two notes have frequency $p$ and $q$ then the interval between them is $p/q$. But while solving a question, I found the answer which is like $q/p$. After surfing different sites I saw there is something like high frequency to low frequency ratio. So I am really confused and want to know what actually right fact is.

Comment: See relevant recent video on the math between musical note intervals https://youtu.be/nK2jYk37Rlg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see precisely what you are asking. One of the main tuning notes A is 440 Hz for instance.  The A 1 octave higher is 880 Hz, 1 octave lower is 220 Hz, etc. The E that is one perfect fifth above A440 is 1.5x or 660 Hz.

However, *equal temperament* is used on a piano keyboard, where each adjacent key is $^{12} \sqrt 2$ higher than the one below it. (I should say on a computerized keyboard this can be the case. On real life pianos, the tuning is a bit different than equal temperament, partly in order to make the most commonly used keys more in tune).

This video may help you more than this explanation

https://youtu.be/1Hqm0dYKUx4

Answer (score 4):

Interval is like distance ... the distance between two points doesn't depend on the order you're given the points, and the interval between two notes doesn't depend on the order you're given the notes in.

The interval between two notes C and E is the same as the interval between the same two notes E and C played in the reverse order — they're both [a major third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_third), which you call an interval of $5/4$. Just like the distance from Rome to Florence is $273$ km and the distance from Florence to Rome is also $273$ km, and not $-273$ km. So distances are always positive and intervals are always fractions greater than one.

Comment: I disagree - in music, you implicitly list the lower note first, so the interval between E and C is a sixth, not a third.

Comment: @Javier: What I meant is: if you play C, then the E immediately above that, that's a third. If you play these same two notes in reverse order, that's also a third. It's only when you're talking about chords that you list the notes in ascending order. Edited to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a convention to define the ratio between frequencies $p/q$ or $q/p$, as long as you know what your talking about: the higher the note you hear, the higher the frequency and viceversa.

The closest interval between the same note (i.e. you're hearing the same sound, higher or lower, as an example the higher note sung by a woman or a young guy and the lower by a stout man) are separated by an octave, corresponding to a frequency ratio $p/q = 2$ or $q/p = 1/2$, being $p$ the frequency of the higher note and $q$ of the same note an octave lower.